# Getting TyperError when trying to print as CSV in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I attached the python script above.

I am trying to print out the information I need in to a csv. Whenever I attempt this, I get a TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function'. I am very new to python so I'm not sure how to address this (or if there are other issues in the script).

```
#print(teams)
with open('players.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in teams:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: remove `, newline=''`

Comment: Indeed, `newline` is not a valid parameter to the `open` function. What makes you think it is?

Comment: nevermind, I think the problem is actually the python version you are using: you should use python 3 in order to have the `newline` argument, you probably are using python 2

Answer (score 2):

You are using Python 2, and the [open](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) function has no `newline` argument.

You should use Python 3 in order to use that argument. See the new [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, use `'wb'` instead of `newline=''` to achieve the same effect. Python 3 uses the latter.